# Why is nodemon not reacting to changes in my src/ folder?

Tags: typescript, next.js, nodemon

When files inside of subdirectories of my `src/` folder are changed, `nodemon` won't react to their changes, however it will react when other files in project are changed.

[Screenshot of the folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aCtjc.png)

`package.json`:

```
    "dev": "nodemon src/server.ts",
```

`nodemon.json`:
*

```
{
   "watch": [".babelrc", "public/locales/**/*.json", "next.config.js", "src/server.ts"],
   "exec": "ts-node --project tsconfig.server.json"
}
```

`ts.config.server.json`:

```
    "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es2017",
        "noEmit": false,
        "outDir": "build/"
    },
    "include": ["src/server.ts"]
}
```

and
`ts.config.json`:

```
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "esnext",
        "module": "esnext",
        "jsx": "preserve",
        "lib": ["dom", "es2017"],
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "strict": true,
        "allowJs": true,
        "noEmit": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "noUnusedLocals": true,
        "noUnusedParameters": true,
        "isolatedModules": true,
        "removeComments": false,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "resolveJsonModule": true
    },
    "exclude": ["dist", ".next", "out", "next.config.js"],
    ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx"]
}
```

Comment: Don't put tags into your title, it should read as a sentence.

Comment: Please, if you can post everything as text, and not as screenshots, e.g. folder structures can be easily copy pasted from the `tree` command's output.

Comment: `When files inside subdirectories of the src/ are changed, nodemon won't react.` This is not exactly clear, could you make your question a bit more specific.

Comment: Edited your post's formatting.

Comment: thanks @ruohola, I owe you a beer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In nodemon.json try changing this:

```
"watch": [".babelrc", "public/locales/**/*.json", "next.config.js", "src/server.ts"],
```

to this:

```
"watch": [".babelrc", "public/locales/**/*.json", "next.config.js", "src/**/*.ts"],
```

Answer (score 1):

@Paolo 's answer seemed to do the trick for `.ts` files!
adding one for `.tsx` though did not work.

The final solution was to add a `ext` field with `js json ts tsx` values!

Final `nodemon.json`:

```
    "watch": [".babelrc", "public/locales/**/*.json", "next.config.js", "src/**/*.ts", "src/**/*.tsx"],
    "exec": "ts-node --project tsconfig.server.json",
    "ext": "js json ts tsx"
}
```

Comment: ext works fine for me as well!

Answer (score 0):

Could you show server.ts file?
Have you changed all the import paths from server.ts?

I am using nodemon with gulp and this is working fine.

```
gulp.task('serve', function (done) {
  nodemon({
    script: 'server/server.js'
  , ext: 'js html'
  , env: { 'NODE_ENV': 'development' }
  , done: done
  })
})
```